# std::filesystem doesn't work in DLL project

Tags: c++, filesystems, std

I feel sorta silly asking this question, but I just cannot find a solution anywhere on the internet.

Notes:
I am using VS2019
C++17 is enabled

My problem is the following:
I want to iterate files in a directory with std::filesystem. To do so, I need to use the directory_iterator. However, when I include the filesystem library, it doesn't find the directory_iterator, so I checked the filesystem header file. It threw me a bunch of errors. I also cannot use experimental/filesystem because for some reason the path class also has errors which make the string functions unusable.

However, when I create a fresh console application, it works fine for me. No errors, directory_iterator has been found, I can iterate without issues.

Here is a small snippet of what the errors I'm being given when trying to compile:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\experimental\filesystem(917,28): warning C4003:  not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'concat'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\experimental\filesystem(921,1): error C2365:  '_InIt': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\experimental\filesystem(921): message :  see declaration of '_InIt'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\experimental\filesystem(921,1): error C2061:  syntax error: identifier '_First_InIt'
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have `using namespace std` anywhere in your code?  This is especially dangerous in a header file.

Comment: As always. [mcve].

Comment: @PaulSanders no, I don't use that.

Comment: Here is an example: [link](https://pastebin.com/5m6JXKXY)

Comment: Alright, update: I didn't know the std library calls it's concat macro concat. Since I had my own macro called concat, they interfered and it didn't work, however it threw the errors in a different place not related to concat..